# Claiming or Completing Task, with a group assigned, in JBPM by a user

Tags: jbpm, kie

I have been working for JBPM 7.56.0 and have modeled a simple workflow having a human task with a Group assigned.

I have been using Kie-server swagger to test the REST end-points for listing & starting/completing the tasks for users belonging to the group that was assigned to the user task.

I am able to get a task listing for all the group users for the given task, but trying to start the task using the endpoint below gives me a 'Can not find task' message with a 404 response code.

Endpoint I did try was - curl -X PUT "http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/emmigrant_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/tasks/19/states/started?user=ra1" -H "accept: application/json"

Would appreciate any help in figuring out the right endpoint?